# Detect pg_dump call with auditd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audit

I immediately apologize for the level of English.

The problem is that there is no way I can add tracking of the pg_dump call to auditd. I've tried many different options, but nothing seems to work. I tried to do it by analogy with the cp command detection, but for some reason it does not work. The cp command is detected, but pg_dump is not.

Example rule:

```
-a exit,always -S execve -F path=/bin/pg_dump -k test_pg
```

Maybe someone came across similar tasks and can help with advice. I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: It would be a bit unusual for `pg_dump` to be in the `/bin` directory. Locate the path to `pg_dump` first by typing `which pg_dump`.

Comment: @Cheatah you was god damn right. I used commands `which` and `whereis` before, but them shows that path of `pg_dump` is `/usr/bin/pg_dump`  and it confused me. After your message, I thought about it and manually tracked where the utility call comes from. It turned out that `pg_dump` is called at the path `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg _dump`. By specifying this path, everything worked. Thank you so much for the tip. I feel insanely stupid.